# using Environment variables to set enterpriseLibrary filepath

Tags: c#, app-config, enterprise-library

I want to set the enterprise library(3.1) path to use Environment variables something like

```
<add name="ExternalEntLibConfig" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
           filePath="%CONFIG_PATH%\SharedEntLib.Config"/>
```

I can use expandvariables to substitute %CONFIG_PATH%

```
SpecialFolder.ExpandVariables(@"%CONFIG_PATH%");
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any "magic" character that I'm missing that will substitute %CONFIG_PATH% with the actual value?
2. Is there any method i need to override while the Enterprise library get load?

Thanks,Pini.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that I don't think there is any magic way to make the substitution happen (correct me if I'm wrong,  folks!).

The good news is that you can create your own `FileConfigurationSource` that does what you want. You should be able to extend `FileConfigurationSource` and implement some version of `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()` in your code before calling the base class.